# Connection string work only on my computer

Tags: c#, sql-server

my connection string is `Initial Catalog=CompainDecumentation.MDF;Data Source=Localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI`
when i take my project to another computer :
1. log file is missing (Solved by remove the .log and it create itself)
2. in the JIT it says Failed to connect to "X" (X is the Authentication name Like Migo-pc\Migo)
now, whats wrong in the connection string how to make it work everywhere

Note: C# Application Connected (ADO.Net) with SQl Server 2005 Express, when i go to the client i setup NetFrameWork 2.0, SQLserver Express, Sql Server Management studio Express.
then i atach the .mdb AND i Expect the project work

Comment: You're source is `localhost` meaning that the database is on your local machine; when you move to another machine it's trying to connect to a database that is on their machine, which doesn't exist.

Comment: great so how to make it work

Comment: Is the instance SQLEXPRESS available on your client's machine. And also try changing Integrated Security = true. I hope it will help. I tried it is working fine for me. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use `Data Source=Localhost\SQLEXPRESS` and expect it to work on the client's machine unless they have a `SQLEXPRESS` instance as well. Based on what you stated you need to change the connection string, **on the client machine**, to `Data Source=localhost`.

However, if you installed the SQL Server with a named instance, the string would look more like `Data Source=localhost\INSTANCE_NAME`, where **INSTANCE_NAME** is the name you gave it during the install.

**Edit based on comments by OP:** so at this point your only problem is this. Change the `Initial Catalog=CompainDecumentation.MDF` to `Initial Catalog=CompainDecumentation`, **make sure** you named the database `CompainDecumentation`, and finally, **make sure** you installed it in mixed-mode allowing for Windows authentication on the **client machine**.

Comment: im sry i didnt get "Based on what you stated you need to change the connection string, on the client machine, to Data Source=localhost" do you mean 'Initial Catalog=CompainDecumentation.MDF;Data Source=Localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI' ?

Comment: @MagedEWilliam, you stated that you installed SQL Server on the client machine -not SQL Server Express.

Comment: the name is Migo-pc\SqlExpress

Comment: Opps its Sql server Express Forgive me im still new

Comment: in this case i will change it and i'll come back :)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your connection string. You need to install the Sql Server Express.

As I can understand from your question you really need a portable database so you can show demo of your application. If this is the case you must go with SQL CE.
Microsoft SQL Server Compact (SQL CE) is a compact relational database produced by Microsoft for applications and for this you really no need to install .

The following programming models are supported by SQL Server Compact 4.0:

- ADO.NET, accessible by using C# or Microsoft Visual Basic
- OLE DB, accessible by using Visual C++ option from within Visual Studio

You can find more http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms172349.aspx

Hope that helps.